# Breaking up the following calculation step by step C++

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I recently came upon the following line of code and I have no idea what the `>>` operator means and how it can be calculated.

```
int dat;
int val;
dat = (125*val)>>8 ;
```

If someone can give me insights to how it works and what the technical name for `>>`, I would be very well appreciated.

Edit: Some of you mentioned about the adequate initialization of `val` for the program to run properly. That is correct, my primary program has initialized a value for `val`, but for the purpose of understanding the notion of the calculation of `dat`, let assume that `val` be equal to an arbitrary integer `n`.

Comment: Bitwise right-shift operator (arithmetic shift, since it replicates the sign bit)

Comment: Easily locatable on an operator precedence chart.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour anyway: `val` has not been initialized.

Comment: @chris: I dont think this is related to operator precedence, since there are brackets.

Comment: @urzeit, The name of any operator is easily found on one, and from there, it's very searchable.

Comment: @chris of course - as the operator name can be found in every good book and in the wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation in the third line takes the value of `val` (which is not defined, you have to initialize it!) and multiplicates it with 125. The result of this operation is bit-shifted to the right.

Bit shifting by 8 means, that all bit positions are shifted by 8 to the right, so that the 256-valued bit becomes the 1-valued bit. Example:

```
259 >> 8
```

In binary representation:
    100000011 >> 8 == 1

whereas the resulting 1 is the first 1 of the binary representation of 259.

A shift right is the same as an division by 2 (rounded to the next smaller integer).

Bit shifting on signed types is dangerous, since shifting negative values *may* result in a shifted sign-bit.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ >> means shift right the code for

```
int dat = (125*val)>>8 ;
```

would be:

```
int dat = 125 * val;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   dat = dat / 2;
}
```

Comment: it is 125, not 128 (`int dat = 125 * val`), just to avoid confusion.

Comment: And the results of `>>` may not be the same as division if the values are negative.  `-1 / 2` gives `0`.  `-1 >> 1` will result in either `-1` or `MAX_INT` (at least on a 2's complement machine).

Answer (score 0):

So to explain a bit:

```
int dat;
int val = 4; //initialized.... for example
dat = (125*val); // dat = 500
dat = 500>>8;
```

500 = 111110100
so 
500>>8 => 1

```
 dat = 1;
```